# Curious translations

Tags: traduction, homonymes

How does one say these in French?

> With my headlights on, I could see the lighthouse.
>
> When I heard the siren, I saw a mermaid.
>
> I want an office with a desk in it.
>
> A walnut is a nut.
>
> My fireplace has a chimney.
>
> I use my tongue to speak a language.

Comment: Most of these use homonyms that don't appear in their English counterparts. I suspect you know that already: one doesn’t come up with all these randomely. Just to satisfy your curiosity: “When I heard the siren, I saw a mermaid” → «Quand j’ai entendu la sirène, j’ai vu une sirène» (nice play on words, actually, that seemingly turns a sound into something visible). In order to avoid this, one may choose «Quand j’ai entendu l’alarme, j’ai vu une sirène».

Comment: How do you say "*L'un cherche la puissance, l'autre cherche le pouvoir*" in English? There are lots of words that have synonyms in one language but not in the other. Asking "how do you say that?" is not really a  question, you know we can't.

Answer (score 5):

Short explanation: each sentence contains two words that translate as one unique French word. These homonyms can be differenciated with the sentence context.

> With my headlights on, I could see the lighthouse.
>
> - Avec mes phares allumés, je pouvais voir le phare.

The “phares” most people turn on are the headlights. The “phare” is probably not a car's headlight because it is singular.

> When I heard the siren, I saw a mermaid.
>
> - Quand j'entendis la sirène d'alarme, je vis une sirène.

Both “sirènes” can be heard, but only one can be seen. Then, we do not have to precise the second “sirène” is a mythologic critture. We still have to add details on the first one in order to show it is about a siren, not a mermaid.

> I want an office with a desk in it.
>
> - Je veux un bureau avec un bureau à l'intérieur

“Je veux un bureau” alone needs a context in order to understand it. In this sentence, it is almost certain I want a room with furniture in it, and not the opposite!

> A walnut is a nut.
>
> - Une noix est un fruit à enveloppe ligneuse.

Using “noix” instead of <del>“arachide”</del> “fruit à enveloppe ligneuse”<sup>1</sup>  is an “abus de langage”.

> My fireplace has a chimney.

French does not have an equivalent to "fireplace". It can be translated to “cheminée, foyer, âtre” these last two being parts of a chimney.

> I use my tongue to speak a language.

When we use “parler” with “langue” (*language*), it is for the quantifier between them: “Je parle une, deux, cinq langues.” However, we just talk. If we absolutely need a translation:

> - J'utilise ma langue pour parler un langage.

<sup>1</sup><sub>Suite à la remarque de @Laurent. S : effectivement, un arachide est une cacahuète, rien à voir avec les noix ! J'ai donc choisi de reprendre la définition du TLFi qui me paraît englober l'ensemble des fruits désignables par "nut".</sub>

Comment: Attention, d'après moi, le français n'a pas non plus d'équivalent pour "nut". Et la noix n'est PAS un arachide. Une noix, c'est une "walnut", les autres ont toutes un nom soit en 1 mot (noisette, chataigne,...) soit du type "noix de ..." (Noix de cajou, Noix de macadamia, noix de pécan,...). La meilleur traduction que je pourrais trouver pour "nut" est "fruit à coque", mais je ne suis pas certains que ces 2 ensemble soient exactement identiques...

Comment: C'est une généralisation de ma part, qui porte effectivement à confusion. *Foyer* et *âtre* sont des synonymes (tant qu'on parle d'une cheminée et pas d'un poêle ou d'une chaudière), qui sont des éléments d'une cheminée. Toutefois, il est fréquent d'interchanger ces trois mots tant qu'on reste dans le contexte d'une cheminée dans une pièce.

Comment: Merci ! Je suis d'accord avec votre affirmation en commentaire. Mon usage diffère. Le Père Noël entre par le cheminée sur le toit et descend jusque dans le foyer, l'endroit où l'on ajoute des bûches quand ça brûle... et on espère que c'est éteint dans ce cas-là ! Mais donc pour moi dire mon foyer dispose/a (d')une cheminée relève d'un truc évident mais je déduis de votre réponse que selon l'usage ça varie. Je n'ai jamais pensé qu'on pouvait aussi parler de la cheminée comme de ce qui encastre le foyer etc. J'en ai appris davantage sur l'emploi du mot _cheminée_, merci !